# One-based column indexing in Emacs

Tags: emacs

How can I change the `(line number, column number)`, shown at the bottom of the buffer, to be one-based?

Motivation: to match the error messages from a compiler.

Comment: Where are the error messages from? The `compilation mode` is usually able to jump to the correct line.

Comment: Yes, see (in particular) *Compilation* and *Compilation Mode* under `C-h i g` `(emacs) Building` `RET`

Comment: Perfect! Answer, and it shall be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `compilation-shell-minor-mode` in my `shell` buffer. clicking on the error `dir/file:100:1:` opens the file and jumps to the hundredth line and the first (i.e. `0`) column of the buffer, which is correct.

see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation-Mode.html

also https://github.com/sboosali/.emacs.d/blob/master/my/my-compilation.el for a simple configuration